# Is it possible to register a DataFrame API function for use in a SQL expression?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

PySpark allows Python functions to be referenced in SQL expressions via UDFs, e.g.:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(col_a="hello", col_b=1)])

def py_len(c):
    return len(c)
spark.udf.register("pyLen", py_len)
df.selectExpr("pyLen(col_a)")
```

But is there a way to register a function that returns a Column expression? As expected, this doesn't work:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sqlf

def add_one(col_name: str) -> Column:
   return sqlf.col(col_name) + sqlf.lit(1)
spark.udf.register("addOne", add_one)
df.selectExpr("addOne(col_b)")
```

Is there a way to accomplish this or something similar? This is so easy to do and such a common pattern when using the DataFrame API that I thought it would be simple in pure SQL, but it doesn't seem that way.

Comment: Does that mean `column_name` is a column in the data frame and you effectively want a dynamic UDF?

Comment: Yes -- I will edit to make it clearer.

Comment: Seems like you're going to have to go with the rdd api here (that may be just because I don't know how to do this, but I can't imagine a spark evaluating row-wise `col()` values at execution time). Are you interested in alternative approaches?

Comment: I was thinking that it would be at JVM compile time, not execution -- because a Column object always has a corresponding SQL expression string, a statement like `addOne(col_b)` will always translate directly to something like `col_b + 1`. Something akin to this in PL/SQL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-expressions.html

Comment: My alternative approach would be to forego the `expr` API altogether and have an interface that used the DataFrame API.

Comment: Compiling `addOne(col_b)` to `col_b + 1` wouldn't make sense because `df.selectExpr("addOne(col_b)")` clearly *intends* to result in `<whatever column name in col_b per row> + 1`. This is what makes your solution tricky. The easiest alternative will be to use something like `sqlf.case()` if you don't have too many distinct values in `col_b`.